# Publishing Custom Master Page For New Subsites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, master-page, publishing, sub-site

I created a site in Sharepoint Designer 2013 and I created a custom masterpage. Then I created new subsites under the site. But these subsites doesn't get my custom masterpage. It has default masterpage. How to publish my custom masterpage for new subsites.

I'm afraid my site is broken. Because,  when I creat new subsite I go to site settings > Look and Feel > Design Manager > Publish and Apply Design and I published my custom masterpage. But my site is broken. My custom masterpage didn't appear. Then I get history version for masterpage I recovered it. Is there any other way?

Please guide me. Kind regards.

Comment: Your site is broken bcoz of your custom master page. Check your master page in SharePoint like clic konm masterpage itself and see it render in browser or not. If not then there is error in your masterpage

Comment: but custom masterpage works. When i publishing, site is broken. Custom masterpage doesn't appear, Default masterpage seem. How there is an error in custom masterpage. Shoul I edit in the masterpage? @ateet

Comment: after publishing masterpage, you tried again to set your custom masterpage on site from look and feel section